# Django Rest Framework - How to create a GIF file from an uploaded video

Tags: python, android, django, django-rest-framework, animated-gif

I have a Django Rest Framework + Android App where the user can upload some video files to my local Django development server. I wanted to show the videos as GIF files via a RecyclerView. I thought that creating the GIF files on server side (Django) would be more efficient than creating them on the client side (device).

So I want to make a GIF file from an uploaded video before storing the video file.
How can I do that in Django ?

Here is my `models.py`:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='Videos/',
                              blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created', )
```

This is how my `views.py` looks like:

```
# used for displaying & creating video items 
class VideoList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, )

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)

        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)

        # the only part we change
        return Response({'videos': serializer.data})
```

And this is the `urls.py` with the url the app uses to upload the video file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('upload/', views.VideoList.as_view())
]
```

The upload of videos from my app works, but I don't know what to do to create also a GIF file version of the uploaded video. 
Which is the best way to achieve that & how can I embed it into my Django-related files such as `views.py` or `models.py`?

I would very thankful for any hint or any advice. Hope someone can help...

Answer (score 0):

```
from moviepy.editor import *
clip = (VideoFileClip("ENTER THE FILE PATH HERE"))
clip.write_gif("output.gif")
```

A simpler idea, make a model in your models.py file probably and then convert the video to gif using that model. That model could look similar to this and once it converts it, maybe use the output where you want to.